# Calculate conditional probability using sample from 3variate normal distribution

Tags: r, probability, conditional-probability, multivariate-normal-distribution

I am working in R and have a matrix (200X3) named X where I have simulated data from a 3variate normal distribution given its parameters (variance-covariance matrix & and mu). My task is to calculate conditional probabilities P(X1>1|X2=1, X3=-2) and P(X1>1|X2+X3=-1)where X1,X2 and X3 the 1st,2nd and 3rd columns of X. I would really appreciate some tips.

Comment: Having data won't help: just perform the calculations using the parameters.  If you want to *estimate* these probabilities from the data, Ordinary Least Squares regression is the solution.

Comment: It is not necessary to do it from the data. I suppose i can use bayes theorem and then calculate the joint and the marginal probability but I think that since i have covariances and a very complex density function the calculations will be quite extreme. Should I just try to standarize it maybe?
Thanks a lot for the response by the way.

Comment: Actually how can I use OLS to estimate these probabilities?

Comment: It's far less complicated than you think.  The theory is completely covered in early chapters of the intro textbook *Statistics* (Freedman, Pisani, & Purves, any edition) for instance--and that's a textbook that includes very few formulas.  OLS provides estimates of the conditional mean and conditional variance, so your normality assumption does the rest.

Answer (score 0):

I think a simple way is using $Plug-in$ estimation.

**1)** estimate parameters of $\mu$ and $\Sigma$ of 3-variate normal based on data. 
  $$(\hat{\mu} , \, \hat{\Sigma})$$

**2)** Calculate the conditional distribution of $X_1|X_2,X_3$ and $X_1|X_2+X_3$  that depend on  $\mu$ and $\Sigma$.

**3)**  using $Plug-in$ estimation for $X_1|X_2,X_3$ and $X_1|X_2+X_3$ by replacing
$$(\mu , \, \Sigma)$$ with

$$(\hat{\mu} , \, \hat{\Sigma})$$

**4)** Based on (3) calculate

$P(X_1>1|X_2=1,X_3=-2)$  and $P(X_1>1|X_2+X_3=-1)$